# Unity can't identify which button is beeing pressed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-ui

I've been trying to make the options in my game being selected by a keyboard input. I can highlight them, but I don't know how to make Unity identify which of the buttons is beeing pressed in order to do a certain action, it's giving me the `NullReferenceException` in line 28 of my code. The cript in question is the `BattleSystem` script, it's attached to the event system, the `battleFirstButton` is the fight button and the `enterKey` is "Z".

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class BattleSystem : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject battleFirstButton;

    public KeyCode enterKey;
    Button selectedButton;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        EventSystem.current.SetSelectedGameObject(null);
        EventSystem.current.SetSelectedGameObject(battleFirstButton);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(enterKey))
        {
            selectedButton.onClick.Invoke();
        }  
    }

    public void SetSelectedButton()
    {
        selectedButton = GetComponent<Button>();
    }

    public void Fight()
    {
        print("Fight option submitted");
    }

    public void Act()
    {
        print("Act option submitted");
    }

    public void Item()
    {
        print("Item option submitted");
    }

    public void Mercy()
    {
        print("Get dunked o-, I mean, Mercy option selected");
    }
}
```

[image]

[image: The four buttons OnClick() functions]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`selectedButton` is a private variable potentially never set to anything, so it's null. Make sure it's set to something before you access it.

Probably the simplest fix to the way you have it set up is:

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(enterKey))
    {
      // Gets the focused button
      selectedButton = EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject.GetComponent<Button>();
      if (selectedButton != null) 
      {
          selectedButton.onClick.Invoke();
      }
}
```